# Making a fixed div scroll horizontally, & return to centre when page is maximised

Tags: jquery, css

I have been hunting around for a solution to my problem and have solved the first half, but have one small outstanding snag that I am hoping someone can help me with.  I am reasonably well versed in html and css, and have been known to make use of the odd bit of very basic php, but am totally new to javascript / jquery, and am very much an amateur  when it comes to web design, so please be gentle with me and explain in simple terms!

I am trying to put together a website with a fixed width of 960px which, in wider browser windows, is centred.  For this I am using the following CSS:

```
#container {
 width:960px;
 margin:auto;
}
```

which is working fine.

At the top of this div, I want to have a fixed horizontal menu which floats above the rest of the page's content, which is the full 960px wide, and which stays glued to the top of the viewport and in view when the user scrolls vertically downwards.

While the window is wider than the 960px wide container, this is easy, and the following CSS works just fine:

```
#top {
 width:960px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
}
```

The problem is that, because the CSS position:fixed is always in relation to the viewport, if the window is shrunk to less than 960px wide, the page gains a scroll bar at the bottom and main content area scrolls to the right, but the fixed menu at the top does not, meaning that the right hand side of it is lost and cannot be accessed.

When searching for a solution to this I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054588/a-fixed-div-with-javascript-to-scroll-when-a-window-is-too-small-doc-type-issue), in which it says that the following jquery code will do the trick:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 $('#top').css('left', -($(window).scrollLeft()));
});
```

Essentially, this alters the css on the #top div to move it left as the user scrolls right.  This seems elegant, simple and perfect for my needs.  After some faffing around trying to figure out how to make this work and where to put it, I have added the following code inside my body tags:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).scroll(function () {
   $('#top').css('left', -($(window).scrollLeft()));
});
</script>
```

So far, so good!  When the page is first loaded, at a browser window wider than 960px, the menu is at the top and centred inside the container div, and stays fixed in place when the main content is scrolled up and down.  Then, when the window is shrunk to less than 960px and a horizontal scroll bar appears, the menu scrolls to the right alonside the main content.  Perfect!  Sadly, there is one more snag....

Although the scrolling then works fine while the page is narrow, if it is once again widened to more than 960px, the floating menu at the top stays over to the left hand side, rather than moving back to the centre along with the main content, because it still has the css "left" property as set by the jquery code again.  This breaks my lovely layout, and means that the menu is no longer in line with the main content.

Somehow, I need to essentially delete this bit of css as soon as the browser window goes above 960px wide and the horizontal scroll bar disappears.

Is there some sort of javascript / jquery that will do this?  I am completely new to all this, and so far searching has got me no-where.....

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have this online somewhere we can see? Or can you paste the HTML?

Comment: Oops - seems this isn't working quite as well as I had initially thought.  I have just realised that the initial, centred layout when the browser is > 960px wide, also breaks when the content is scrolled vertically downwards, because the vertical scrolling also kicks in the jquery and sets the left property in the top div's css to 0, meaning that it jumps to the left hand side of the page.  So as well as a fix for returning the menu to the centre when the page is maximised after being shrunk, I also need to figure out how to only have a horizontal scroll trigger the existing jquery.... :(

Comment: tsdexter - yes, I do!  The page I am testing it on is here:

Comment: http://huntleywood.co.uk/NEW/v2/

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding to your jquery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $('#top').css('left', 'auto');
    } else {
        $('#top').css('left', -($(window).scrollLeft()));
    }
});
```

Does that work?

You can use this to just detect left scrolling:

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
    //your code here
    $('#top').css('left', -($(window).scrollLeft()));

    lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
}
});​
```

Comment: Right, one thing at a time.  Because I keep making silly mistakes!  The first bit, to re-centre the menu when the window gets maximised, works a treat - thanks!  Re the 2nd bit, give me a minute and I'll test it....

Comment: Right, when I add the code to stop the menu moving left when the vertical scroll bars are used, this bit works (ie the menu stops jumping left inappropriately), but this seems to break the horizontal scrolling, too, so I'm back to the situation where, when the window is shrunk, the menu no longer scrolls.  But I'm not 100% sure I'm implementing this correctly.  Can you tell me exactly which bit of code should go where you have "//your code here"?

Comment: I updated it with your code. I think you might have the layout/build incorrect - you shouldn't necessarily need so much JS on a simple page. Tell me how you want the page to layout/function without any of the bugs and I'll see if I can help restructure the HTML/CSS. You can email me if it's easier.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will drop you an email about it.....  I hugely appreciate the help, but don't seem to be able to up-vote your answers as I'm not reputable enough! ;)

Comment: *lol* nope - assumed I would find some way to email you by clicking on your username - just returned here to say I can't find it and ask if I was being blind or stupid! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Yay!  Just goes to show what waiting 'til the morning and having a clear head will do.  Just needed to add a very simple "if" statement to the code which scrolls the menu to the left.

Here is the final solution, with big thanks to tsdexter!

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if (($(window).scrollLeft())>0) {
  $('#top').css('left', -($(window).scrollLeft()));
 }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
 if ($(window).width() > 960) {
  $('#top').css('left', 'auto');
 }
});
```

Now seems to be working picture-perfectly in Firefox - haven't tried the others yet!  *fingers crossed*....

Comment: Just a quick update - although this works, it is sadly slow and laggy.  When scrolling back to the left on a narrow screen, the css doesn't seem to update fast enough, leaving the menu bar too far to the right compared to the rest of the page.  *sigh*  This is worse in IE, where it is noticeable at reasonable scrolling speeds, but also happens in firefox and chrome if you scroll left fast.  The problem seems to be the "if" statement, remove that and the scrolling goes back to being super fast & smooth but I'm back to  having the issue of the menu moving horizontally when scrolling vertically:(

Comment: I did try that at the time (and again, just now), but apparently I don't have the "reputation" to do so!  :/  Sorry....  Would if I could!

Comment: Haha, you need to build up that rep :P